# Function AJAX no refresca dinámicamente los datos de tabla

Tags: php, javascript, ajax

Tengo una tabla que quiero cambiar dinámicamente un campo booleano si/no (valores 0/1) mediante POST. El tema es que al hacer click sí me actualiza la tabla pero visualmente veo el dato en pantalla modificado. Tengo que darle a F5 para refrescar y ver el dato modificado:

```
<a href="#0" onclick="language(<?php echo $id_appl ?>,'application',0); return true;"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok"></span></a></li>

function language($id, $campo, $valor){
    //get the input value
    $.ajax({
        //the url to send the data to
        url: "colleges_save2.php",
        //the data to send to
        data: {id : $id, campo: $campo, valor: $valor},
        //type. for eg: GET, POST
        type: "POST",
    });
}
```

El PHP

```
$campo = $_POST['campo']; // nombre del campo
$id = $_POST['id']; // id del registro 
$valor = $_POST['valor']; // valor por el cual reemplazar 

// sql para actualizar el registro 
$query = mysql_query("UPDATE applications SET ".$campo." = '".$valor."' 
WHERE id_application = '".$id."'" ); 
?>
```

Comment: Creo que te falta el .done(function(obj). Es decir lo que debe hacer el llamado de ajax al tener respuesta del script PHP.

Comment: Que es lo que quieres ver actualizado en tu tabla pon una imagen de lo que tienes y lo que deseas que se actualice luego del ajax

Comment: $.ajax({
        //the url to send the data to
        url: "colleges_save2.php",
        //the data to send to
        data: {id : $id, campo: $campo, valor: $valor},
        //type. for eg: GET, POST
        type: "POST",
  }
 }).done(function(obj){
 )});

Comment: pues no se si será porque lo aplico mal pero me sigue sin refrescar... supuestamente el object es el id de la tabla?

Comment: El código de javascript que tienes acá en el foro es el mismo que tiene en tu código? O falta algo?

Comment: es el mismo que tiene mi código

Comment: Un llamado de ajax se compone de 2 o más partes, la primera es la solicitud que se hace al servidor en donde tienes el código PHP. En ese código PHP debes tener una respuesta (que es lo que quieres mostrar) que debe ir en formato Json, para que javascript la acepte. Segundo el llamado ajax debe tener el código en donde recibe la respuesta del código PHP y tu lo procesas y lo muestras en el DOM en donde tu lo desees. En el comentario que te puse más arriba dice como. Sino puedes, hablamos por el chat y te ayudo.

Comment: Pues si puedes me gustaría hablar por chat... he puesto success pero nada, actualiza y desaparece el dato...

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/74938/discussion-between-raul-a-and-vieira).